# Why does "converges almost surely" equal "almost always"?

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading "A first look at rigorous probability theory" chapter 5. There is the lemma but I am struggling in the proof.

Lemma 5.2.1 Let $Z,Z_1,Z_2, \dots$ be random variables. Suppose for each $\epsilon > 0$, we have $P(|Z_n - Z|\geq \epsilon \quad i.o.) = 0$ Then $P(Z_n\to Z) = 1$.

Proof: $P(Z_n \to Z) = P(\forall\epsilon >0, |Z_n-Z|<\epsilon \quad a.a)$ ...........

---

Similarly, in a solution, it wrote $$P(\lim_n X_n=X) = P(\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}(\liminf_n |X_n-X|<\epsilon))$$ which is basically the same as to say $P(Z_n \to Z) = P(\forall\epsilon >0, |Z_n-Z|<\epsilon \quad a.a)$.

---

My question is, why $P(Z_n \to Z) = P(\forall\epsilon >0, |Z_n-Z|<\epsilon \quad a.a)$? What is the difference between $P(\forall\epsilon >0, |Z_n-Z|<\epsilon \quad a.a)$ and $P(\forall\epsilon >0, |Z_n-Z|<\epsilon \quad i.o.)$? and why

$P(Z_n \to Z) \neq P(\forall\epsilon >0, |Z_n-Z|<\epsilon \quad i.o.)$

EDIT: To be clear, definition of "infinitely often" and "almost always" are:

Given events $A_1,A_2,\dots \in \mathcal{F}$, we define
$$ \limsup_n A_n = \{A_n \quad i.o.\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$$
$$ \liminf_n A_n = \{A_n \quad a.a.\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$$

Comment: What does "almost always" mean?  I'm familiar with "i.o." but not "almost always."

Comment: a.s. a.s. <---> a.a.

Comment: "Almost always" means "For every integer except a finite number of them". "Infinitely often" means "For infinitely many integers". Thus, "Almost always" implies "Infinitely often", but the reverse implication does not hold.

Comment: That $x_n\to x$ in a metric space means that, for every positive $\epsilon$, $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$ almost always, by definition of convergence. The result is not related to probability theory.

Comment: Finally, note that "Almost always" is equivalent to "For every integer large enough".

Comment: Given events $A_1,A_2,\dots \in \mathscr{F}$, $\{A_n\quad  i.o.\}=\limsup_n A_n$ and $\{A_n\quad  a.a.\}=\liminf_n A_n$

Answer (score 3):

In this context, "a. a." or "almost always" means "for all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$".  The condition that $\forall\epsilon >0, |Z_n-Z|<\epsilon$ for all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is the definition of what it means for $(Z_n)$ to converge to $Z$.

On the other hand, "i. o." or "infinitely often" just means "for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$".  This is much weaker.  For instance, suppose $Z=0$ whereas $Z_n=1$ if $n$ is even and $Z_n=0$ if $n$ is odd.  Then for any $\epsilon>0$, $|Z_n-Z|<\epsilon$ is true for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$, namely all odd $n$.  However, it is not true that $(Z_n)$ converges to $Z$.